# How do i fix this particular error in Excel when using Azure Machine Learning to do Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: excel, machine-learning, data-analysis, sentiment-analysis, azure-machine-learning-service

Obtaining error when using Azure Machine Learning add-in in Excel when doing Sentiment Analysis. I keep receiving the following error when i use Azure ML to predict.

Error i receive is: Error! {"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.","details":[{"code":"ColumnNamesMustMatchSchema","target":" (AFx Library)","message":"inputColumnNames: Column names must match the schema. Column names only in input: RT Survey Comments. Column names only in schema: tweet_text"}]}}

Also received this error after using the trim function to remove extra spacing thinking it would help.

" Error! {"error":{"code":"LibraryExecutionError","message":"Module execution encountered an internal library error.","details":[{"code":"ColumnNamesMustMatchSchema","target":" (AFx Library)","message":"inputColumnNames: Column names must match the schema. Column names only in input: RT Survey Comments. Column names only in schema: tweet_text"}]}}

[image: 1]

I changed the name of the column where i want results to be to match the schema thinking it would resolve the errors and it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, i notice that i had the box selected for "My Data has Headers". Once i unselected the box, i was able to achieve the results of the sentiment analysis.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXbw.png)